# FCM: firebase getToken options( ServiceWorkerRegistration, vapidKey)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

So this is how the firebase docs describe the get token function:

> getToken ( options ? :  { serviceWorkerRegistration ?: ServiceWorkerRegistration ; vapidKey ?: string } ) : Promise < string >

> Optional options: { serviceWorkerRegistration?: ServiceWorkerRegistration; vapidKey?: string }

> Optional serviceWorkerRegistration?: ServiceWorkerRegistration
> The service worker registration for receiving push messaging. If the registration is not provided explicitly, you need to have a firebase-messaging-sw.js at your root location. See Retrieve the current registration token for more details.

I'm just trying to figure out how to use the service worker option in my code. Do I just put the file location inside of the getToken('/file-location') like this? Or do I import a function that registers my custom firebase service worker? I might just be stupid but these docs are barebones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have your `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in your (web)server root, you can just call `.getToken()`, and your service worker will be automatically loaded and used.

If you have your `firebase-messaging-sw.js` at `/my-other-folder`, then you will need to call it this way:

```js
const swRegistration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/my-other-folder/firebase-messaging-sw.js');
const token = await fcm.getToken({
  serviceWorkerRegistration: swRegistration,
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I had it in my root server but this bug kept coming up and wanted to try it this way.